# Filtering multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering

I'm trying to create a filter with javascript with 4 input fields so I'm guessin 16 combinations of possible searches.  I can search all 4 at once or 1 input at a time but for some reason when I add other statements I get wierd results.  Is there a better way to implement a filter?

```
var unfilteredFloorplans = floorplanJSON.floorplanData;

filteredFloorplans = [];

for (var i = 0; i < unfilteredFloorplans.length; i++) {

    if (unfilteredFloorplans[i].city == req.body.cityName && 
        unfilteredFloorplans[i].building == req.body.buildingName && 
        unfilteredFloorplans[i].bedrooms == req.body.minBedroom && 
        unfilteredFloorplans[i].baths == req.body.maxBathroom) {

           console.log(unfilteredFloorplans[i].city);
           filteredFloorplans.push(unfilteredFloorplans[i]);
    } 
}
```

So now I need to write 15 more if statements? Rather than copy them in I'd like to ask if this is correct and does anyone know how you could implement this with a switch statement?

**Edit:** And when I say 15 more statements I mean one for if they just pick city, andother if they pick city and bedrooms etc. It just seems inefficient

Comment: And when I say 15 more statements I mean one for if they just pick city, andother if they pick city and bedrooms etc.  It just seems inefficient

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework assignment. Also, why do you use "==" instead of the typesafe "==="? Why do you filter always by equality? (i.e. "bedrooms == minBedroom" instead of "bedrooms >= minBedroom"). Why are the fields named inconsistently? (e.g. bedroom_s_ versus minBedroom (without "s"))

Comment: Totally unclear what you're trying to do. If you read again and again your own question - you'll understand.

Comment: It's not homework and if it was I'd be creative enough so you wouldn't know.  As for why I use == instead of === it's not going to make a difference here

Comment: I wrote a question that asked about a javascript filter for 4 input fields.  I showed the entire code to process 1 search that was for if a user selected all 4 input fields.  I asked do I need to create 15 more combinations of searches since there are 2**4 permutations I believe.  I'm saying and agreeing it's inefficient to do it the way I am doing it.  So Im asking what is the best practice for implementing a filter that will filter through 4 inputs.  I did one of the searches, is there a better way so I don't have 15 more if statements to cover the other choices a user could make

Comment: what if there were 20 input fields do I now write 300 if statements?

Comment: @baryjones23saturn Can you clarify what your **goal** is in the question? Also, you may want to look into JavaScript's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) methods

Comment: I'm really just trying to find out what the best practice for implementing a filter where a user had a choice of 4 drop downs.  That gives the user 16 different combinations.  I wrote 16 if statements and it works but feels wrong.  I am just wondering is there a best practice or a better way or is this the way it has to be done.

Comment: @baryjones23saturn Regarding your comment about creativity: So it really *is* homework?

Comment: @baryjones23saturn You are correct; using 16 if statements *is* wrong, even if it works. Breaking it up into chunks and using tools such as filter are much better approaches

Answer (score 2):

A minimal fix would be to combine your "and" with "or", but note how this turns the code into a hard-to-read mess:

```
var unfilteredFloorplans = floorplanJSON.floorplanData;

filteredFloorplans = [];

for (var i = 0; i < unfilteredFloorplans.length; i++) {

    if ((req.body.cityName == '' || unfilteredFloorplans[i].city == req.body.cityName) && 
        (req.body.buildingName == '' || unfilteredFloorplans[i].building == req.body.buildingName) && 
        (req.body.minBedroom == '' || unfilteredFloorplans[i].bedrooms == req.body.minBedroom) && 
        (req.body.maxBathroom == '' || unfilteredFloorplans[i].baths == req.body.maxBathroom)) {

           console.log(unfilteredFloorplans[i].city);
           filteredFloorplans.push(unfilteredFloorplans[i]);
    } 
}
```

(BTW, this looks like a good exercise for combining conjunctions with disjunctions.)

**Edit** I'd recommend to put the filtering into a separate function, and to introduce an additional helper function. Also, use a more consistent naming and use "===" instead of "==".

```
function filterByEquality(formValue, dataValue) {
    if (formValue === '') return true;
    if (formValue === dataValue) return true;
    return false;
}

function filterFloorplan(form, data) {
    if (!filterByEquality(form.city, data.city)) return false;
    if (!filterByEquality(form.building, data.building)) return false;
    if (!filterByEquality(form.minBedrooms, data.bedrooms)) return false;
    if (!filterByEquality(form.maxBathrooms, data.bathrooms)) return false;
    return true;
}

var unfilteredFloorplans = floorplanJSON.floorplanData;
filteredFloorplans = [];
for (var i = 0; i < unfilteredFloorplans.length; i++) {
    if (filterFloorplan(req.body, unfilteredFloorplans[i]);
        console.log(unfilteredFloorplans[i].city);
        filteredFloorplans.push(unfilteredFloorplans[i]);
    } 
}
```

You can reduce this code even further by learning about the Array.filter method. And you should fix the bug where for some fields should use ">=" or ">=" instead of "===". But I'll leave those things as an exercise.

Comment: @vog I believe he posted that before you expanded your answer; nonetheless, I kinda agree with his sentiment. If I ever got a Pull Request with the code you gave (correct though it may be), I'd make sure to introduce the submitter to array filters.

Comment: Hey this is very helpful I think you guys answered my question in directly.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Sure, but that was IMHO the smallest issue with the code.

Comment: @vog Hmm, I'm not sure I'd agree with your assessment - you basically just encapsulated the multiple `if`'s into their own function, which will need to be repeated anyway.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham thats what I was asking how should it be what is the best practice, you don't have to write code but how should I have done it?

Comment: @baryjones23saturn I'll add an answer in a couple of minutes with a basic example; you should be able to use that as a starting point

Comment: @vog I believe that the use of multiple if statements and incomprehensible logic in the question as you said leads to it being low quality. A simple google search would suggest a map/filter solution to this homework question and I think not upto SO standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example of what your code may look like (in this example, I hardcoded the values representing the `input` choices):

```
var unfilteredFloorplans = [{
  city: 'NY',
  building: 'A',
  bedrooms: 2,
  baths: 1,
}];


var filteredFloorplans = unfilteredFloorplans.filter(
  function(el) {
    return el.city === 'NY' && el.building === 'A' && el.bedrooms >= 1 && el.baths >= 1;
  }
);

console.log(filteredFloorplans);
```

The anonymous function being called inside the `filter` can be replaced with a named function like so:

```
function filterFloorplans(floorplan) {
  return floorplan.city === 'NY' && floorplan.building === 'A' && floorplan.bedrooms >= 1 && floorplan.baths >= 1;
}

var filteredFloorplans = unfilteredFloorplans.filter(filterFloorplans);
```

You'll likely want to use this route since you can have any combination of the 4 input choices. As such, you'll want the `filterFloorplans` function to be "built-up" from other, smaller checks:

```
function testCity(userInputCity, floorplanCity) {
    return userInputCity ? userInputCity === floorplanCity : true;
}

function filterFloorplans(floorplan) {
  return testCity('NY', floorplan.city) && floorplan.building === 'A' && floorplan.bedrooms >= 1 && floorplan.baths >= 1;
}
```

This *should* be enough to get you started; feel free to comment if you get stuck